Phantom inputs in GRUB
Recently my desktop has been having an issue where GRUB is detecting phantom up/down keystrokes and randomly moving the cursor through selected options. There are normally no input devices connected to the computer. (I use it as a headless work machine) If I plug in a USB keyboard the issue immediately goes away, and comes back the second I unplug the USB device. Once the computer boots into Ubuntu I see no evidence of phantom keystrokes with or without a device plugged in.
This issue popped up in the last month or so with no major changes that I'm aware of. Right now I've "solved" it by leaving in an old usb keyboard. Does anyone forsee any future issues with this? Or have suggestions on how to troubleshoot here? I've opened up the computer and don't see any obvious issues that would be causing interference but also not really sure what I am looking for.

Your description implies an issue with your hardware, firmware and not the installed OS, as before you exit your bootloader (GRUB) the OS isn't actually running. Issues with firmware are device specific, and may get worse quickly; or never get any worse, but can be a sign of a flaky component in your machine. You've provided no specifics (no mention of what Ubuntu product/release) nor what hardware, but have indicated it's mostly a hardware related issue that is best dealt with on hardware/firmware sites. I'd use generic hardware troubleshooting (and not using your installed OS)

Is your UEFI firmware the latest vendor had to offer? Compare to vendors support site
sudo dmidecode -s bios-version Grub does not have its own driver. It uses the firmware or same as you get when you go into UEFI to change settings. When Ubuntu installed then Ubuntu uses its own keyboard driver.
